# Odd Pivot Table Sum

Tags: excel, pivot-table

The following is a screenshot of a pivot table I have created in Excel.

[image]

The odd thing is that the column total of the **distinct count** is being displayed as `71` but if you highlight the values (or add them manually) then the total comes to `90` (as you can see in the corner of Excel).

When I generated the pivot table, I select the "Add this data to the model" option, so that I can use the **Count Unique** option.

Does anyone have any idea why the two values are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason becomes obvious from the example in the picture.

You group by the `Name` column containing the values `{'A','B','C'}` and for each of the values there is an entry of `{'A','B','C'}` in the `Char` column.

No you can see, that for **each** element there are **3 distinct values** in the column `Char`, however, in **total** there are **also only 3 distinct values**.

The grand total can here not be interpreted as the `Sum` of the above, but as the `distinct count` of the whole table.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I am with you. So you're saying that the `90` is the sum of the **distinct value of code** values, and the `71` is the number of distinct counts of **code** against **uuid**?

Comment: That's it exactly!

Comment: That's great! I've just gone back to the original data, and removed duplicated against **uuid** and **code** and it leaves 71 results. I've then done the same for **uuid**, **detailed id** and **code** and it returns 90 results. Thanks for the answer.